# Hosting and domain registrations for multiple clients under a single hosting account of mine?

Tags: web-hosting, clients

I am finally getting regular work designing, developing, and deploying websites for small businesses and individuals. So far the websites utilize single-user content management systems, so the websites create, as far as I know, minimal load on the shared servers.

I have always required that each of my clients purchase annual shared hosting at Dreamhost. For domain registration, I ask that they register with Dreamhost, but some already have a registered domain elsewhere and this is fine with me. I do this so the billing issues are the client's responsibility, not mine.

**My question is**: Since I can register unlimited domains and connect them to my one shared hosting account at Dreamhost, should I not be requiring clients to individually pay for shared hosting and a domain? Should I actually be paying for one hosting account and then hosting all of my client's websites on that account? As I said before, I currently have each client buy their own hosting, because I feel that, for example, if there is high traffic to their site, there would be less a chance of the site going down than if their site was hosted with many others on one account.

I am famous for being long-winded, please let me know if I can clarify at all. Thanks!

Comment: Is that dreamhost account one "regular" account? Or a reseller account?

Comment: @John - It is a regular account. I am not familiar with reseller accounts (researching them as we speak).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a reseller account and set up your clients using that (don't know if dreamhost offers those). That way you have control over their hosting but only have one bill to pay. You also can charge them for their hosting and either give them a really good deal or make yourself even more money. If someone's site starts using a lot of resources get them their own account or dedicated server. The chances of that happening is small but if it does migrating to better hosting would be part of the plan anyway.

I use Hostgator's reseller plan and it handles everyone seamlessly and even gives them their own Cpanel control panels, etc.

Comment: Apparently, Dreamhost does not offer reseller accounts. DH does offer the ability to host unlimited sites on one hosting account. Do you think, with the small-traffic sites that I am developing, that I should host multiple sites on one shared account? I agree that if a site were to require lots of resources that I should move it to a dedicated server.

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me. As long as they provide you with the tools to host multiple sites on one account it essentially is the same thing. Not quite as powerful but still effective.

Answer (score 1):

If you "stuff" all of your clients into one account will they get their own Control panel/Stats etc?

I run a Design & Hosting company and am a reseller for [EZPZHosting](http://ezpzhosting.co.uk/).

£10 a month will get your a reseller account with WHMCS (billing/invoice system) and then you can resell hosting to your clients AND give them all the bells and whistles that John has mentioned including backup, email accounts, forwarding, auto responders one step Software installs, PHP etc etc etc, you will also get a client area for invoicing, support ticket system and a knowledgebase.

Their level of support is also brilliant and so far the best I have come across.

Speak to Dan, he will be able to advise you.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Since I can register unlimited domains and connect
>   them to my one shared hosting account at Dreamhost, should I not be
>   requiring clients to individually pay for shared hosting and a domain?
>   Should I actually be paying for one hosting account and then hosting
>   all of my client's websites on that account? As I said before, I
>   currently have each client buy their own hosting, because I feel that,
>   for example, if there is high traffic to their site, there would be
>   less a chance of the site going down than if their site was hosted
>   with many others on one account.
>
> I am famous for being long-winded, please let me know if I can clarify
>   at all. Thanks!

Simply do the following: order a reseller hosting package and create a separate account for each client and grant access to each customer.

The customers will pay you for hosting their single account and domain registration if necessary.